# Why am I getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) or bus error (core dumped) when trying to populate a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

So I am trying to use a pointer to a struct of `MonsterAttacks` as the data that belongs to an element of a linked list. In order to do this I try to populate a struct of `MonsterAttacks` and then pass that along with a null ptr to a next node to a function called create. However somewhere in the `populate` method a segmentation fault error occurs. I am working with three files `list_demo.c`, `linked_list.h` and `linked_list.c`. I will build all the the functions that make up a fully functioning linked list, well hoping I can as soon as I get pass this error. Been dealing with this error for about two days and I showed my professor and he could not figure out why its happening, it seems to come from the `populate` function. I have tried to return a pointer to a strut in which case I get a bus error, and I have tried almost every variation of getting input and storing it on the strut. I even deleted the function and tried to populate it in main, but nothing works. I am new to C and my professor helped me out for about an hour debug this problem and he finally gave up, so any help would be appreciated.

**list_demo.c**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "linked_list.h"
 #include <stdlib.h>



 void populate(struct MonsterAttacks *m){

    printf("Enter the name for the Monster \n");
    scanf("%40s",m->monsterName);
    puts("What is his/her attack location?");
    scanf("%40s",m->attackLocation);
    puts("What are the number of victims this monster has demolished?");
    scanf("%ud", &m->numOfVictims);      
    m->attackID = 0;
}

int main(void)
{

   node* tmp = NULL;
   struct MonsterAttacks *tmpMonst = (struct MonsterAttacks *) 
   malloc(sizeof(struct MonsterAttacks));

   if(tmpMonst == NULL){
      printf("Error allocating memory");
   }
   else
      populate(tmpMonst);

   node *head = create(tmpMonst,tmp);

   free(tmpMonst);
   return 0;
}
```

**linked_list.h**

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST
#define LINKED_LIST


typedef struct node{
   struct MonsterAttacks *monsterAttack;
   struct node* next;
} node;


struct MonsterAttacks{
   unsigned int attackID;
   char monsterName[41];
   char attackLocation[41];
   unsigned int numOfVictims;
};

/*
   create a new node
   initialize the data and next field

   return the newly created node
*/
node* create(struct MonsterAttacks *m,node* next);



#endif
```

**linked_list.c**

// from zentut.com, heavily adapted

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linked_list.h" 


/*
   create a new node
   initialize the data and next field
   return the newly created node
*/
node* create(struct MonsterAttacks *m,node* next)
{
    node* new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error creating a new node.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

     new_node->monsterAttack->attackID = 0;

     new_node->next = next;

     strncpy(new_node->monsterAttack->monsterName,m->monsterName,41);
     strncpy(new_node->monsterAttack->attackLocation, m->attackLocation, 41);
     new_node->monsterAttack->numOfVictims = m->numOfVictims;

      return new_node;
}
```

**Btw running on Red Hat using gcc compiler**

Comment: When posting questions like this it is nice to reduce the code to a minimal reproductive form.

You provided three files, much of the code is clearly not relevant.

The process of deleting down to a minimal reproduction also helps highlight the area of the fault and typically allows you to see it yourself.

Comment: @lod Thank you I will give only what needed I just wanted to be complete make sure I was linking files correctly and all that...trying to rule out any possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new_node->monsterAttack->attackID = 0;
```

Allocating memory for `new_node` does not allocate memory for the `MonsterAttacks` struct inside it. That is why dereferencing `monsterAttack` to get its `attackID` is causing a seg fault.

A minimal **working** code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Moved the two structs out to make a minimal reproducible code
/*  #include "linked_list.h" */

struct MonsterAttacks{
    unsigned int attackID;
    char monsterName[41];
    char attackLocation[41];
    unsigned int numOfVictims;
};

typedef struct node{
    struct MonsterAttacks *monsterAttack;
    struct node* next;
} node;

void populate(struct MonsterAttacks *m){

    printf("Enter the name for the Monster \n");
    scanf("%40s",m->monsterName);
    puts("What is his/her attack location?");
    scanf("%40s",m->attackLocation);
    puts("What are the number of victims this monster has demolished?");
    scanf("%ud", &m->numOfVictims);      
    m->attackID = 0;
}

node* create(struct MonsterAttacks *m,node* next)
{
    node* new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error creating a new node.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    // Just add this line
    new_node->monsterAttack = malloc(sizeof (struct MonsterAttacks));

    new_node->monsterAttack->attackID = 0;
    new_node->next = next;

    strncpy(new_node->monsterAttack->monsterName,m->monsterName,41);
    strncpy(new_node->monsterAttack->attackLocation, m->attackLocation, 41);
    new_node->monsterAttack->numOfVictims = m->numOfVictims;

    return new_node;
}

int main(void)
{
    node* tmp = NULL;
    struct MonsterAttacks *tmpMonst = (struct MonsterAttacks *) 
        malloc(sizeof(struct MonsterAttacks));

    if(tmpMonst == NULL){
        printf("Error allocating memory");
    }
    else {
        populate(tmpMonst);
    }

    node *head = create(tmpMonst,tmp);

    printf("Name: %s\n", tmpMonst->monsterName);
    printf("num victim: %d\n", tmpMonst->numOfVictims);

    free(tmpMonst);
    return 0;
}
```

When you allocate memory for `new_node` in `create(...)`, you allocate memory on the heap for a structure of type `node` to hold all the variables it contains. In this case, `monsterAttack` in `node` is initially a pointer to a struct that is pointing to nowhere. You need to explicitly allocate memory for the `monsterAttack` pointer to point to.

Comment: I'm kinda wrapping my head around what you are saying. It's essentially just allocating 64 bits for `MonsterAttacks` since its a pointer and tha't the default for pointers, right? That makes sense also just as @lod made sense, but I still think that it's coming from populate function somehow. When I put `printf("Crashed here");` before `node *head = create(tmpMonst,tmp);` crashed here is never printed.

Comment: My head is spinning rn, I commented out `node *head = create(tmpMonst,tmp);` and "Crashed here" was printed. YOU WERE RIGHT! How would you allocate that struct inside the node and dereference it?

Comment: @Squanchy Are you compiling with optimization flag on i.e., something like `gcc -O2 <file>` or `gcc -O3 <file`? That can re-order your code when things get optimized. Just add that line I mentioned and things should work.

Comment: @Squanchy I already explained how to allocate it in my answer. See the line of code with the comment "Just add ..."

Comment: sorry I did not see your code earlier just the comment, it worked. No seg fault anymore. Jeez I guess my professor is as lost as me with C memory management. I'm doing `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -o  lab4  *.c` to compile. Thanks I would have been stuck on this for a lot longer if it wasn't for you.

Comment: Now I can build the rest of the program TY!

Comment: This case is simple enough to spot by mere inspection but in future learn how to compile your code with debug symbols, no optimization, and step through the code in a debugger.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: @bruceg pointed out the lack of semicolon, this malloc isn't the issue. @lightalchemist have highlighted that the second one is the fault.

```
struct MonsterAttacks *tmpMonst = (struct MonsterAttacks *);
malloc(sizeof(struct MonsterAttacks));
```

Your `malloc` call is wrong, malloc allocates and returns a pointer to the memory. You ignore/discard the pointer value.

Later code seems to assume that `tmpMonst` points to this allocated memory but there is no link between the two.

Try `struct MonsterAttacks *tmpMonst = malloc(sizeof(struct MonsterAttacks));`

Comment: the OP doesn't have a semi-colon at the end of the first line you quote from his main routine. His malloc is ok there.

Comment: Right, just saw that.  I'll edit and leave the answer up so it is clear for others.

Comment: @lod What you said actually made sense and I was hoping that would kill the segmentation fault  error, but I still get it.